# How to get user input in Android Studio

Tags: android, input

How do take user input and save as variables? I have followed a tutorial step by step yet every time I try and run the program it closes the app in the emulator.

I have re-watched the tutorial a number of times and everything seems to match.

Logcat states that the issue lies within the onClick listener returns a null object reference at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity however the code seems to look fine to me.

```
public class Macros extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Integer kilojoules;
    private Integer carbohydrates;
    private Integer protein;
    private Integer fat;

    EditText kilojoulesInput;
    EditText carbohydratesInput;
    EditText proteinInput;
    EditText fatInput;

    Button saveButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_macros);

        kilojoulesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kilojoulesInput);
        carbohydratesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.carbohydratesInput);
        proteinInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.proteinInput);
        fatInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fatInput);

        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                kilojoules = Integer.valueOf(kilojoulesInput.getText().toString());
                carbohydrates = Integer.valueOf(carbohydratesInput.getText().toString());
                protein = Integer.valueOf(proteinInput.getText().toString());
                fat = Integer.valueOf(fatInput.getText().toString());

            }
        });
    }

    private void showToast(String text){
        Toast.makeText(Macros.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public Macros(){
        // No args constructor
    }

    public Macros(Integer kilojoules, Integer carbohydrates, Integer protein, Integer fat){
        this.kilojoules = kilojoules;
        this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
        this.protein = protein;
        this.fat = fat;
    }

    public Integer getKilojoules() {
        return kilojoules;
    }

    public void setKilojoules(Integer kilojoules) {
        this.kilojoules = kilojoules;
    }

    public Integer getCarbohydrates() {
        return carbohydrates;
    }

    public void setCarbohydrates(Integer carbohydrates) {
        this.carbohydrates = carbohydrates;
    }

    public Integer getProtein() {
        return protein;
    }

    public void setProtein(Integer protein) {
        this.protein = protein;
    }

    public Integer getFat() {
        return fat;
    }

    public void setFat(Integer fat) {
        this.fat = fat;
    }

}
```

Logcat:

Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 26980
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.Macros}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myapplication.Macros.onCreate(Macros.java:37)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

Comment: Check ID saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button) it might be null as it not receiving the id

Comment: Make sure you have the **Button** with id **save_button** in your layout xml file.

Comment: Now the app is working without closing however when I use showToast() to see if it stored the values correctly, it shows as null. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: You've declared the `showToast()` but You're not calling it anywhere. Also, what is the parameter `text` in the `showToast()`?

Comment: got it ! thanks guys.